# IBM Worklight - Is it possible to make a videocall or a realtime video transfer?

Tags: video-streaming, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

Is it possible make a videocall over Worklight server? Or maybe build an app on Bluemix integrated with Worklight to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight Adapters, which go through Worklight Server, are not meant for such high-volume data transfer. So using the built-in features is not recommended.

I also do not believe Bluemix was meant for that either, I could be wrong.

I would actually look into the native capabilities of the OS the app is meant to run on (iOS, Android, etc) to see what are the options for video streaming. Again, this is *not* the core functionality or what Worklight Server is meant for. This is purely client-side, not server-side (Worklight Server, Bluemix).

You can look at OpenTok, which allows using WebRTC in mobile web-based apps.
https://tokbox.com/opentok/

There's a Cordova plug-in for it, for iOS and Android, which you [may be able to integrate to your Worklight application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid): https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok